# Custom UIActivityViewController-like view that slides up and down

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, custom-view

Is there a way to subclass or customize `UIActivityViewController` to create a sort of custom view? For example, see the image below from the app [Overcast](https://overcast.fm/). I want to create a view similar to that, where if you tap a button, the view pops up and when you tap outside of the view, it slides back down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an UIView ? Set it's initial frame's y value to -self.customView.frame.size.height and animate it's frame to the normal position using `[UIView animateWithDuration]`

```
-(void)showCustomView{
    [self.customview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -self.customView.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.height+self.customView.frame.size.width, self.customView.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.size.height,  self.view.bounds.size.height-self.customView.frame.size.width, self.customView.frame.size.height)];

    }];
}

-(void)hideCustomView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -self.customView.frame.size.height,  self.customView.bounds.size.height+self.customView.frame.size.width, self.customView.frame.size.height)];

    }];
}
```

Add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` and call `hideCustomView` when tapped outside the `customView`